# How to describe a process that resists changes in velocity?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm writing a scientific paper in which I'm describing a process affecting the sliding of an object (a glacier in this case). This process resists both acceleration and deceleration. I'm currently saying that it acts as a "buffer" but I feel that doesn't properly describe the property I'm referring to.

**Does it?**

**Are there other nouns (or phrases) that can be used in this case?**

Here is the paragraph in its current form for more context:

> Isolated cavities display persistent high water pressures, often close
>   to overburden. Therefore, under steady basal sliding speeds, they
>   would offer little resistance to movement. However, their fixed volume
>   would result in a pressure drop if sliding accelerates, or a pressure
>   increase if it decelerates. In other words they can act either as
>   sticky spots when basal sliding speeds up or as slippery spots when it
>   slows down, working as a buffer for basal sliding variations.

Comment: I don't see a problem with *buffer* personally, but your paragraph does have some other problems.  // Note you used *buffer* as a noun, not an adjective.  (There's also a verb as you probably know.)

Comment: I got all exited and wrote up an answer using the word **attenuate** http://www.dictionary.com/browse/attenuate but I think it only focuses on range when used with electronics ? http://www.dictionary.com/browse/attenuator?s=t  I do think it could be understood to applie to velocity range modifying other words but then it misses the point of brevity

Comment: You're the science writer and you're asking about what makes glaciers resist changes in velocity? There's an Earth sciences SE site just to let you know.

Comment: @Zebrafish I'm a frequent collaborator of Earth Sciences SE. I'm not asking about the science, but about the wording.

Comment: It's called ***momentum***.

Comment: You should say "fixed volume", "sliding accelerates", and "slows down".

Comment: I agree with Cuagau, but he needs to provide evidence for his answer. What you should do is pay attention to your basic English if you are writing scientifically for a living — present tense third person "s" for example. I have corrected (most) of the mistakes in your question.

Comment: @David I appreciate very much your edits. And I know I have to work on my basic English. However, I do a more thoughtful review process before publication in a journal than I did before posting it here. Thanks!

Comment: sticky spots when basal sliding speeds up or as slippery spots when it slows down: Wouldn't it be: slipping spots when basal sliding speeds up and sticking spots when basal sliding slows down??

Comment: Buffers are separate zones. Are these acting as separation zones??

Comment: Also, if the cavities can do two opposite things with regard to velocity (speed up or slow down), how can these be buffers? Also "acting as a buffer", not "working as a buffer".

Answer (score 2):

In chemistry, a *buffer* resists changes in its acidity, or some other state, rather than velocity, specifically.

Therefore, I'd consider "mass" and "inertia" (as in "inertia tensor"). These specifically characterize resistance to changes in *velocity*.

Answer (score 1):

**negative feedback loop**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_feedback

If velocity increases, the system works to decrease it towards a given point. If velocity decreases, the system works to increase it towards the same point. These two processes, based on your paragraph, converge towards a constant basal sliding state.

Answer (score 0):

Buffer is absolutely the right word, in its less common definition of "something that lessens a change that would otherwise occur" (e.g. pH buffer), and your meaning is totally clear to me.

Comment: We're looking for [answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) that provide some explanation and context. Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).